# UIWebView and search query

Tags: url, search, wiki

I've start to learning UIWebView and I have next problem. When I'm trying to use next code:

```
 NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",lookedCity];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchString]]];
```

or:

```
NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%@",lookedCity];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchString]]];
```

my WebView doesn't loading page. But if I use standart URLs (ex. google.com), all works fine. 
In case with Wiki, I tried use [WikiApiObjectiveC](https://github.com/prine/WikiApiObjectiveC), but even example doesn't work. How can I solve this problem? The best solution will be with Wiki URL.

Comment: Just a short notice: I made an update of the WikiApiObjectiveC Library and it is now working with IOS 7 and asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!
The reason, why my URL doesn't work, was in cyrillic symbols in my `searchString`. Solution: `urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`